# Does anyone know what this living creature is?

Tags: species-identification

There are two different things I am trying to identify. I live in Lexington, Kentucky. The first one I started seeing was a small white larvae looking worm thing. They would very in size but never bigger than a few centimeters long and very thin.  I started seeing these around my house about two months ago.  I had not seen them before.  It seemed like they showed up all of a sudden.  They were in the floor and on the furniture.  I never would see them move. When I would try and pick them up or investigate, at the slightest touch they would turn to liquid almost like water, clear.  Just disappear.  The other form I am seeing is a bit bigger I don't know if they are both the same species just in various stages or if they are 2 separate species.  The second ones I seen were almost an off white with rings vertically around its body. With hair all over them.  Some were hairier than others and they were not all the exact same color.  It seemed to me that they used their hair as a weapon or defense not sure how that was intended.  They started showing up on my hanging cloths in my closet as well.  Shortly after we started noticing small holes in our cloths.  I call them creatures since I am not sure what they are.  They then started burrowing into us. I never seen the darker one with hair burrow but for sure the small white larvae looking one.  But only me.  Not my kids or husband.  The doctors can't tell me what they are.  The darker one in the picture came out of my leg.  When I got it out it was still alive.  They seem to prefer my nose and sinus's.  I spent hundred on exterminator and have not seen anymore.  The pest control company said they had never seen them before.  The one picture of the white larva is one that I had to download.  I accidently lost all of my pictures on a phone before they were downloaded to my computer.  That picture is identical to what I have found.  I may have more pictures.  I will go thru all of them in the morning and try to add some here.

Hairy:

[image]

White in colour:

[image: White in colour]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Could you please edit your post and give the location of where you took the pictures?

Comment: Do you have better pictures? Give the size? Is there a reason one of the pictures is 5 years old?

Comment: I have lost some of my pictures due to a phone issue.  I will go thru all pictures I have in the morning and get some more added.  I had to download that picture, but it is identical to the ones in my house.